# The remote server returned an error: (425) Can't open data connection

Tags: c#, azure, windows-server-2012, ftpwebrequest

I implemented ftp servers on Azure platform - Window Server 2012 following http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/enable-ftp-access-on-windows-azure-vm/ link. In summary, I created ports (2500-2504) and used them for FTP services. In same time, I created dataport  (1000-1005) and registered them through azure port as endpoints.

I created App Service under Azure Platform. While I debug ([FtpWebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) command - Download, Upload & ListDirectoryDetails) this app service in my workstation, it works fine. But this app service program is sometimes throwing error when it's in Azure platform. It returns "The remote server returned an error: (425) Can't open data connection." error.

Any idea? Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If one is not using: `using(){}` statement on `IDisposable` objects, then it is possible to get ftp error code 425 if one makes separate enough requests

Reason is: that traffic between azure hosted ftp server and azure site is Fast, way too fast for imperfect code to work properly, while locally debugging(very slow) or locally against remote ftp is slow as well and therefore works